# Is there a way or sample to open or close MCU connection dynamically in LiveSwitch Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am developing multi-user conference and it is almost done. Users are to register to LiveSwitch gateway and create MCU(Multiple Control Unit) connection, and open or close it when it needs. Several users can do this. Now, I am going to make a race for these users to connect or disconnect to LiveSwitch gateway. Total number of users could be registered is limited. So users who are trying to connect can race like horses.
I have tried this way.
`var connection = channel.createMcuConnection(audioStream, videoStream); connection.open(); connection.close();`
I thought I could do it using these functions, but I don't know how I can do it.
If there is someone who has experience in this or has some examples, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's kind of race and I have found that it could not be solved because I have only promise from its process. Retrieval time could be undetermined on front end side and it should be maintained on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by using a kind of signal system together with the liveswitch MCU server.
Basically, we would be able to set the maximum number of clients and it should be managed by a kind of signaling server.
And then on liveswitch sdk(client's side), we can detect one of clients based on low-bandwidth to unregister the client itself.